# no agent could be found with the following capabilities msbuild visual studio azureps - Hosted agent

Tags: azure, msbuild, devops, azure-devops

Trying to run a build in the new Visual Studio Team Services on a hosted build agent. The only way I get it to fly is when I download the agent and run it locally. I want to bulid it using microsoft servers and not my own computer. But then I get the message:

`"no agent could be found with the following capabilities msbuild visual studio azureps"`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do have an Azure PowerShell build task in your build definition?  Also, can you check the capabilities of the hosted build servers in your account and make sure they have AzurePS capability you need (Settings>Control Panel>Default Collection>Agent Queues.

Comment: Can you share your build definition?

Comment: @bmoore-msft  - "No agents are registered or you do not have permission to view the agents."

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT - I have created a build def directly in VSTS with 2 steps: Visual Studio Build and Azure Web App Deployment

Comment: So you cannot see Hosted Build Agent in Hosted Queue?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT Now I can! It didn't show the last few times I checked! But it appears to be solved now!

Comment: Glad to hear that. :)